# iPhone webapps - scrolling and AJAX problems

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I'm now building a webapp for iPhone, and I have problem with the scrolling on an ajax compoment.

Basically, I have a php page which is changed according to the function clicked on a button, and this page's size isn't a set height, so because of that I added the iScroll script which allows me to make it scrollable (because I needed a fixed header & footer), and what happens now, is that because the page is being loaded dynamically, the iScroll doesn't know it's height - so it gets stuck, I tried using refresh function on different pages, i'm afraid it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found a solution:

using jQuery, simply write this below your scroller div, and it should work.

```
<script>$('#scroller').css('height', (window.innerHeight - 1) + 'px');</script>
```

that is for those who use iScroll 4.